# RegEx with powershell and then replace

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

So I have this variabe:

```
Frontend=http://xxxx-xxx.xxx.se/nexus/service/local/repositories/xxxxx_Releases/content/xxx/1.1.1.2/xxxx-1.1.01.2.nupkg
```

Now I want a powershell that takes out only the 1.1.1.2   (regex?)

Then this nr should be replaced in a property file (propfile.properties) looking like this

```
FE=1.1.1.1
```

So the 1.1.1.1 should be replaced with 1.1.1.2

Is this possible to get to work with powershell?

EDIT. The numbers looking for in the variable would be 1.X (0-3).X (0-X).X (0-X)

Comment: It should be, but we may need a bit more info.  i.e. are you always looking for `1.1.1.2`, or any `#.#.#.#`?  What's the range of those numbers (e.g. is there any limit as there would be for an IP, or not as with a version number)?  Could there be more or less than 4 numbers/3 dots?  Is the rest of the URI always consistent, or can some bits change; if so, which bits?  Does `1.1.01.2` change too / is it significant?

Comment: $Frontend -replace '^.*\/content\/[^\/]+\/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\/.*$','$1'

Comment: Updated the question. It is a version nr

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the numbers for a start:

```
$str = "Frontend=http://xxxx-xxx.xxx.se/nexus/service/local/repositories/xxxxx_Releases/content/xxx/1.1.1.2/xxxx-1.1.01.2.nupkg"
$str -match '^(.*?)((\d\.){3}\d)(.*)$'
$matches[2] # 1.1.1.2
```